# Table of Dynamic Disks

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, list-manipulation, geometry, interface

I'm trying to create a dynamic interface to generate disks depending on 3 parameters : x-coordinate, y-coordinate and radius. The disks are generated as soon as the "export" button is pressed. I'm trying to make a table of disks but I can't link the dynamic objects and the creation of disks. Any idea?

```
Manipulate[Manipulate[Column[{{points = Eingabefeld4}}], Style["Armierung", 12, Bold],{{Eingabefeld4, ArrayReshape[{}, {Eisen, 3}]}, Labeled[Grid[
  Table[With[{i = i, j = j, phi = phi}, 
    InputField[Dynamic[Eingabefeld4[[i, j]]], 
     ImageSize -> Tiny]], {i, Eisen}, {j, 3}]], 
 " X                     Y                    phi", Top] &},Button["Export", {export = Table[Disk[{i, j}, phi], 1, Eisen]}]],Control@{{Eisen, 1}, InputField[]}]
```

The number of disks depends on "Eisen."

[image: Example with 3 disks]

Comment: do you get what you need if you change `Button[...]` to `Button["Export", export = (Disk[{#, #2}, #3] & @@@ points)]` ?

Comment: Exactly what I wanted Big thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Manipulate[Take[Eingabefeld4, Eisen], 
 {{Eisen, 1}, InputField[]},
 Dynamic@Panel[Column[{Style["Armierung", 12, Bold], 
     Labeled[Grid[Table[With[{i = i, j = j},
             InputField[Dynamic[Eingabefeld4[[i, j]]], ImageSize -> Tiny]],
                {i, Eisen}, {j, 3}]],
       {Row[{"   X", "Y", "phi"}, Spacer[70]], "Eingabefeld4"}, {Top, Left}], 
     Button["Export", export = Disk[{#, #2}, #3] & @@@ Take[Eingabefeld4, Eisen]]}]], 
 Initialization :> {Eingabefeld4 = ConstantArray[0, {50, 3}]}]
```

[image]